# Prove that bitstrings of length $n+1$ with $m$ 1-bits always start with $1\dots 10$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $m$, $n$, $k$ be integers such that $0\le m\le n$ and $0\le k\le m$. Prove that: $$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n-k}{m-k}=\binom{n+1}{m}$$
by pointing out that bitstrings of length $n+1$ with $m$ 1-bits always start with $1\dots10$ where $k$ is the number of ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote down almost the whole solution to the problem in question by yourself.

Let us count the number bit strings of length $n+1$ containing exactly $m$ ones.

On the one hand, it should be just $\binom{n+1}{m}$, which coincides with RHS.

On the other hand, let us count the number of such strings with exactly $0 \le k \le m$ ones in the beginning of the string. In this case, $(k+1)$-th bit should be 0, hence, there remains $n - k$ bits to fill with either zeros or ones, and exactly $m-k$ of them should be ones (since we want to end up with $m$ ones in total). So, we merely get $\binom{n-k}{m-k}$. Now, we just need to sum it over $k=0..m$ to get the total number of ways, you will get LHS.

Thus,
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\binom{n-k}{m-k} = \binom{n+1}{m}$$
as desired.

Comment: I mean, the left side is the number of all bitstrings with length n+1, m 1 bits, and starts with 1..10 . The right side is the number of all bitstrings with length n+1, m 1 bits, with no mention of 1..10. How do we know the two solutions solve the same problem, thus the equal sign?

Comment: @whatever There can be m + 1 possible cases: either the bitstring starts with exactly 0 ones, or 1 ones, or 2 ones, ..., or $m$ ones. All of these scenarios don't intersect with each other, i.e. it can not be the case that the string starts with exactly 2 ones and exactly 3 ones at the same time. But one of these scenarios holds anyway. So we can just sum the number of ways to get the first scenario, the second scenario and so on, to get the total number of ways. This is called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum

Comment: @whatever In other words, if we have $S_k$ -- the set of bitstrings starting with exactly $k$ ones then $S_0, S_2, ..., S_m$ will be disjoint sets and their union will be exactly the number of all bitstrings containing exactly $m$ ones. Thus, we can just count it by summing up $|S_0| + |S_1| + \dots |S_m|$

Comment: If it can be proven that the two problems' solutions are equal to each other, then the claim that bitstrings with length n+1, m 1 bits and starting with 1..10 are subsets of all bitstrings with length n+1, m 1 bits must be False. How do we know it is False? Given that, how do we know "their union will be exactly the number of all bitstrings containing exactly m ones". What if the union of all set $S_i$ is missing some other bitstrings?

Comment: @whatever Well, any bitstring starts with a number of ones at the beginning (maybe 0 ones), doesn't it? For example, 0010100110 starts with 0 ones at the beginning; 1110010100 starts with 3 ones at the beginning; 1111111010 starts with 7 ones. But it can not contain $> m$ ones at the beginning since the total number of ones should be $m$. So, any bitstring belongs either to $S_0$ (0 ones at the beginning), or $S_1$ (1 ones), or $S_2$ (2 ones), ..., or $S_m$ ($m$ ones at the beginning). I.e., exactly one of $S_0, S_1, ..., S_m$ must contain our bitstring. So, the union of them also contains it.

Comment: In other words, because $S_i$, with $0\le i\le m$, has exactly $m$ 1 bits and there can't be more than $m$ 1 bits, the sum $|S_0|+|S_i|+...+|S_m|$ must be the number of all bitstrings with m 1 bits. I think I understand it now..

Comment: @whatever Yes, exactly. To be precise, it equals to the cardinality of the union of these sets, but since they are disjoint, then it just equals $|S_0| + |S_1| + \dots + |S_m|$, as you said.